# Solving an equation with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, polynomials

I want to use complex numbers to solve the following problem:

$x^2 = 95 - 168i$. I am sure there are a few ways of doing this but the way I want to do it is to let $x = a + bi$ and then solve for $a$ and $b$. However I am finding this quite difficult as when I square $a + bi$ I can not solve specifically for one variable. The help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. $2ab = -168$ (from equating the imaginary parts) means you can express $a = \frac{168}{2b}$, and eliminate $a$ from the equation equating the real parts. The resulting equation should be a quadratic with two solutions.